# What is the best (widely accepted) way for sending data (messages) to server

Tags: c#, messaging

I have a C# application (which is the client) and I have a server. Now the server gets and sends all sorts of messages which are strings to the client, I am using `StreamWriter` for this, now the sending message on the client and the server looks pretty the same, I take the string encode it to UTF-8 and then send it

```
public void SendMessage(String p)
{
    if (p != "")
    {
        string StringMessage = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        try
        {
            swSender.WriteLine(StringMessage);
            swSender.Flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

now,the strings I send is something like this:

```
"SUBJECT@@@@SOMEDATA1<><>SOMEDATA2<><>SOMEDATA3
```

This causes some problems, and makes me think. Is this the way big applications send/ receive data? Because it looks pretty silly. If no, then can some one provide an example on how big applications send messages?

Also: my way of sending messages makes me make big nested if

For example:

```
if(Subject="something")
    do something
else if(subject="something else")
    do something else
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Send self-describing data.  Xml.  The corner stone of Soap and other interop protocols.  Consider WCF.

Comment: what do you mean by self describing data? can you post an exmaple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all greatly depends on your application's needs.
Generally speaking: no, inventing your own protocol is not a good idea.

There are quite a few ways to send messages from client to server.
I'd suggest you to do some reading on WCF, or if you are in .NET 2.0 than .NET Remoting.
Also, you might want to consider to send HTTP messages, as there are a shitload of frameworks to do that.

Comment: if interoperability is also one of your requirement, WCF Rest service is your friend

Comment: Im using the mvc pattern,should the model be connected to the WCF client that gets data from the server? or should the WCF client act as the model itself?

Comment: The model is neither client nor anything is connecting to it. The model is simply the definition of your business objects. You should create both client and server that would pass the Model objects between them

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use XML-RPC. I used [this for .NET](http://www.xml-rpc.net/faq/xmlrpcnetfaq-2-5-0.html). I followed the instructions w/o modifying it and got the client/server working within 30mins and another 10 to modify it to my liking. Essentially you call functions normally and through the magic of the library it will block for the server to execute the code and it will return results. RPC = remote procedure call.

If your using asp.net use the instructions labeled IIS even if your on linux using fastcgi or apache. I ignored that which was a mistake because it was labeled IIS. There is a .NET Remoting option (if the server isnt asp.net but another app) thats available.

A not as good option is to learn webclient and post json strings to the server. Then read the response as json. XML-RPC is pretty standard and suggested.

Comment: Maybe im wrong but i dont think its a good thing to make calls to fucntions on the server from the client without any flitering... thanks anyway i will look thorugh it.

Comment: @BlueGene: Typically you have authentication functions (or a parameter for a long api key) for anything that requires user login/authentication. OAuth is a popular method. The remotes calls i made so far never required authentication but encryption wise you can throw the url behind https and you wont have to worry about sniffing/man in middle attack. However if your using .NET and a self signed cert .NET will complain and you need to turn off something. For that look up ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback and assign it a function which always return true.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx) Method

instead UrlEncode()

Comment: How will it help me solve my problem, i am not talking about the encoding at all , it doesnt matter how i encode, what does matter is that i'm not sure that i need to send data this way